# Como pegar SGV do highcharts

Tags: php, highcharts

Preciso configurar meu http para gerar os graficos do highcharts, apos essa configuração esse servidor recebe um sgv ou json para salvar meu grafico no como png, como pegar o sgv que gerado pelo grafico do highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o *SVG*, você precisa do `id` ou algum identificador da tag que você colocou o *chart*, por exemplo o meu código a seguir eu coloco meu *chart* na `div`:

```
<div id="Chart"></div>

// codigo da pagina

<script>

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: "Chart",
                type: "area",
            },
            // Codigo do seu chart
        });

var chart = $("#Chart").highcharts().getSVG();

</script>
```